# How to use ifconfig to show active interface only

Tags: command-line, networking, osx, interface

By default `ifconfig` will show me all available interfaces , but what if I just want to display `active` ones? Like, `en0` only in below.

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 14:10:9f:e0:eb:c9 
    inet6 fe80::1610:9fff:fee0:ebc9%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet X.X.X.X netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 101.6.69.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    **status: active**
en3: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 32:00:14:e7:4f:80 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    **status: inactive**
```

Notice `ifconfig en0` will not satisfy, `en0` is not always the active one ;)

I'm running Mac OS X.

Comment: Hi @jordanm, my goal is to to get IP address of currently active interface, often a wireless or wired Ethernet interface.

Comment: how do you define the active interface?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To get a complete description of all the active services, try:

```
ifconfig | pcregrep -M -o '^[^\t:]+:([^\n]|\n\t)*status: active'
```

This simple regex should filter out only active interfaces and all their information.  I sugest you put an alias for this in your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile file (maybe ifactive?)

To just get the interface name (useful for scripts), use:

```
ifconfig | pcregrep -M -o '^[^\t:]+:([^\n]|\n\t)*status: active' | egrep -o -m 1 '^[^\t:]+'
```

You have to install [pcregrep](http://pcre.org) for this to work.  It's on [macports](http://www.macports.org) in the pcre package.  Alternatively, this *should* work with GNU grep using `grep -Pzo` instead of `pcregrep -M -o` but with the rest the same, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: @gavin-s-yancey your solution has a couple of problems. First, it shows all the interfaces without an active IP address. Second, egrep is not doing what it is supposed to, just getting the first result. I would suggest this:
<code>ifconfig | pcregrep -M -o '([^\n]|\n\t)+inet ([^\n]|\n\t)+status: active'</code>

Comment: @lasantha The question asks about "active" interfaces, which is a property of an interface on MacOS, regardless of whether the interface has an IP associated with it.  My regex finds the interface(s) marked as active.

Answer (score 5):

Following will print out only those interfaces that are configured to have an IP

```
ifconfig | grep "inet.*broadcast"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are not adverse to some bash scripting, you can do this:

```
for i in $(ifconfig -lu); do if ifconfig $i | grep -q "status: active" ; then echo $i; fi; done
```

That's will list out the active network interfaces. Tested on Mac OS X 10.13.

The nice thing is that you don't need to install anything.  Just run the above in a Terminal.

Comment: This should be the best answer, however `ifconfig -lu` will not work on debian. But OP is using MacOS anyway, so this solution would work on systems with BSD's `ifconfig`. I posted another answer below which does the same without using `ifconfig -lu`

Answer (score 3):

I had to do this recently where it wasn't known if eth0 or eth1 would be up, but the system does not have `pcregrep`.

Here was my solution:

```
for interface in /sys/class/net/*; do [ `cat $interface/operstate` == "up" ] && ifconfig `basename $interface`; done
```

`operstate` gets checked first, and if it matches `up` then run `ifconfig` on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to print the “entry” if it contains `status: active`, then you could use something like this *awk* program as a filter to the *ifconfig* output:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN            { print_it = 0 }
/status: active/ { print_it = 1 }
/^($|[^\t])/     { if(print_it) print buffer; buffer = $0; print_it = 0 }
/^\t/            { buffer = buffer "\n" $0 }
END              { if(print_it) print buffer }
```

When each “entry” starts (a line is empty or does not start with a Tab), start saving the entry in a buffer. Append to this buffer any subsequent lines that start with a Tab. Watch for the magic string `status: active`; if a line like that was seen, print out the buffer (the previous “entry”) when a new “entry” starts (or the input ends).

Save the above program text in a file and use it like this:

```
ifconfig -a | awk -f /path/to/file
```

Or, if you `chmod +x` the file, then you can simplify it a bit:

```
ifconfig -a | /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comments and question, it seems you actually want to just get the interfaces that have an IP address assigned to them.

You can do this quickly with `ifconfig` and `grep`.

Running the command:

```
ifconfig | grep 'Link\|inet'
```

Should produce something similar to:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:22:33:44:55
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:22:33:44:66  
          inet addr:192.168.0.8  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

This would show each line with a interface name and and IP if they had one.

Some more specific REGEX magic might get you exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks but where is `active` consideration ?

Comment: if there is a line after the interface, then it has an IP address assigned to it, and by what I gather you mean, it would constitute as 'active'.

Answer (score 1):

I wish the question was a bit clearer. Assuming that by `Active interface only`, you meant to show the name of active interfaces only (In my case `UP` and `RUNNING` status `active`) without any other details. Then try this:

```
ifconfig | \
  grep "UP\|RUNNIG" \
  | awk '{print $1}' \
  | grep ':' \
  | tr -d ':' \
  | grep -v lo
```

The output would look like:

```
en0
en1
en2
bridge0
p2p0
awdl0
llw0
utun0
utun1
utun2
utun3
en6
```

Adjust the `grep -v` field and add in more unwanted interfaces like `loopback` --> `lo` etc, if necessary.

Now, if you want and you would need to check whether the interfaces found are active at present. Then we can just simply pass them as an argument for `ifconfig <interface>` like shown below:

`[[ $(ifconfig en0 | grep -w active) ]] && echo "en0 is active"`

Simplifying this further and implementing it in a function:

```
checkActiveInterfaces()
{
  local intARR=( $(ifconfig | \
      grep "UP\|RUNNIG" \
      | awk '{print $1}' \
      | grep ':' \
      | tr -d ':' \
      | grep -v lo) );
    intARR=( $(printf "%s\n" "${intARR[@]}" | sort -u) );
    for i in "${intARR[@]}"; do
      [[ $(ifconfig $i | grep -w active) ]] && {
       echo "$i"
    }
    done
}
```

Executing this function will return only the active interfaces. In my case:

```
awdl0
en0
llw0
```

Answer (score 1):

`netstat -i` will show you a list of all active interfaces, networks, addresses (ip4, ip6, MAC), and a few more columns of stats on macOS versions ranging from High Sierra (10.13) to Monterey (12.3) (the 2 systems I have easy access to).

```
% netstat -i
Name       Mtu   Network       Address            Ipkts Ierrs    Opkts Oerrs  Coll
lo0        16384 <Link#1>                       7680002     0  7680002     0     0
lo0        16384 127           localhost        7680002     -  7680002     -     -
lo0        16384 localhost   ::1                7680002     -  7680002     -     -
lo0        16384 mac-manager fe80:1::1          7680002     -  7680002     -     -
en0        1500  <Link#6>    a4:83:e7:73:2b:b8  4393235     0  2854958     0     0
en0        1500  mac-manager fe80:6::1479:f3f9  4393235     -  2854958     -     -
en0        1500  192.168.162   192.168.162.196  4393235     -  2854958     -     -
en1        1500  <Link#7>    82:98:60:06:e0:01        0     0        0     0     0
en2        1500  <Link#8>    82:98:60:06:e0:00        0     0        0     0     0
:
:
llw0       1500  fe80::6c3f: fe80:b::6c3f:2fff        0     -        0     -     -
utun0      1380  <Link#12>                            0     0        2     0     0
utun0      1380  mac-manager fe80:c::8eb3:ce45        0     -        2     -     -
:
:
utun10     1380  <Link#26>                            0     0        3     0     0
utun10     1380  mac-manager fe80:1a::7e37:30c        0     -        3     -     -
en4        1500  <Link#22>   00:50:b6:9b:20:7a   178041     0     8093     0     0
en4        1500  mac-manager fe80:16::106d:4e6   178041     -     8093     -     -
en4        1500  10.1.2/24     macmanager.myne   178041     -     8093     -     -
```

Comment: OK the question states 'using ifconfig' but I don't think that's a must-have, this should be the accepted answer IMHO ;)

Answer (score 0):

Get ACTIVE interface MAC only:

```
cat /sys/class/net/$(ip addr | awk '/state UP/ {print $2}' | sed 's/.$//')/address
```

Comment: Note that MacOS does not have `ip` by default; you need HomeBrew for that, then run `brew install iproute2mac` once. Source code of it is at https://github.com/brona/iproute2mac

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution. I am running MacOS X like the asker.
The following command line filters the output of ifconfig through grep to print just the active interfaces.

```
ifconfig | egrep 'status: active' -7 | egrep '^en\d\d?:'
```

On my machine that gives me a result like this, showing only the active interfaces:

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
en11: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
```

Obviously I invoke it through an alias in my shell config file, so I never actually have to type it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the command you want to show all interfaces that are currently on:

```
scutil --nwi
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ ifconfig | grep "inet addr:" | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | sed -e 's/Bcast//' | cut -d: -f2
```

How it works:

- ifconfig
- Grep for lines containing "inet addr"

  - These lines contains the IPs.
- Grep for lines that do not contain "127.0.0.1"

  - We usually do not care about localhost.
  - -v is inverted grep
- From remaining lines, remove the "Bcast"
- Cut field 2 using ":" as a delimiter

  - Prints the answer.