# how do i get interface name, ip and mac from active interface only (except lo)

Tags: networking, command-line, mac-address, ip-address, ubuntu-mate

I use [this command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445913/266428) to get the name of my network interfaces and their mac address

```
ip -o link | awk '$2 != "lo:" {print $2, $(NF-2)}' | sed 's_: _ _'
```

out:

```
enp2s0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
wlp1s0 YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
```

and this one to get the IP:

```
ip addr show $lan | grep 'inet ' | cut -f2 | awk '{ print $2}'
```

out:

```
127.0.0.1/8
192.168.1.23/24
```

or [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/147777/408537):

```
ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

or [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37212665/8747573):

```
ifconfig | grep -E "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{ print $2 }' | cut -f2 -d: | head -n1
```

out:

```
192.168.1.23
```

What command can I use to know (the order is not relevant):

> interface name | IPv4 address | MAC address

example:

```
enp2s0 192.168.1.23 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

in a single line, but only from active interfaces (except lo) (for ubuntu 20.04)?

I have tried [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103241/how-to-use-ifconfig-to-show-active-interface-only) but it did not work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bash` this works:

```
paste <(ip -o -br link) <(ip -o -br addr) | awk '$2=="UP" {print $1,$7,$3}'
```

but it relies on the `ip` output being in the same order for `link` and `addr`.  To be sure, you could use `join` with `sort` instead:

```
join <(ip -o -br link | sort) <(ip -o -br addr | sort) | awk '$2=="UP" {print $1,$6,$3}'
```

In `sh` command substitution isn't available, so it couldn't be quite as concise as this.

Comment: great, but almost. your command output comes out with ipv6 instead of ipv4. i think {print $1,$6,$3} (exclude net /24 please)

Comment: Oww, there you go. On _my machine_ it gives the IPv4 address. Fair enough, `ip` doesn't claim to produce machine-parsable output, so we shouldn't be trying. Its json output (`-j`) should be better - but then it requires e.g. `jq` on the system.

Comment: it's weird for me. the first 'paste' command works fine, and the second I must change {print $1,$7,$3} to {print $1,$6,$3}. Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: is there a way to exclude netmask /24?

Comment: It's not weird, it actually needs to be $6 in the second (I have corrected this), because `join` merges the join columns so there is one less. Yes, there are uncountable ways to get rid of the `/24`. Awk has `gsub`, or you could pipe everything through `sed -Ee 's./[0-9]+..'`. But the issue remains that you can't rely on `ip` output having any specific order or number of columns.

Comment: great works, thanks

Comment: I wonder if `-o` actually does anything when `-br` is used. Btw there's `-4`.

Comment: Someone knows how to escape the commands to be able to put it in an alias in bashrc?